# Plesk issue appeared without doing anything. 500 Zend_Controller_Exception

Tags: linux, ssh, zend-framework, plesk, plesk-onyx

a few days ago I logged into my plesk and got this error. 
researching just got me the info, that permissions might be set wrong.
could anyone please help me what i need to do in ssh to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Hey, Sorry. I managed to fix the issue by myself. It was about the Plesk Extension SEO Toolkit which overloaded the space limit. I deactivated the extension and removed the file to fix it.